# How to install the '!!' command?

Tags: debian, command-line, command-substitution

I was trying to use `!!` on my new install of debian and I get the following error:

```
$ sudo !!
sudo: !!: command not found
```

I do I gain use of `!!`?

Also what can I call `!!` so that I can actually google something about it?

Comment: I have a feeling there's an XY problem going on here. What are you trying to accomplish by running that command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing the **history** function of your shell when you refer to `!!`

I'm not sure what shell you are using.  From `man bash`:

```
HISTORY EXPANSION
   The  shell  supports a history expansion feature that is similar to the
   history expansion in csh.
...
Event Designators
   An  event designator is a reference to a command line entry in the his‐
   tory list.  Unless the reference is absolute, events  are  relative  to
   the current position in the history list.

   !      Start  a  history substitution, except when followed by a blank,
          newline, carriage return, = or ( (when the extglob shell  option
          is enabled using the shopt builtin).
   !n     Refer to command line n.
   !-n    Refer to the current command minus n.
   !!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1'.
```

Is there anything in your shell history?  When you type the `history` command do you get any output?

I'm not able to duplicate the error you see:

```
~$ ls -l | head -1
total 54324
~$ sudo !!
sudo ls -l | head -1
total 54324
~$
```

Comment: thanks, my default shell was not bash, changing that worked

Comment: There are times when you want to turn history expansion off (for example if you want to `echo "!foo"`) -- do that with `set +H` and turn it back on with `set -H`